# How to get if the plus key is pressed

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I'm fairly new to pygame and I was trying to get the state of the plus (+) key off of the main keyboard, not the numpad variant. The docs for pygame at [pygame.key docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) say to use K_PLUS but that doesn't seem to work.

I wrote the following example code that should print "Pressed" when the plus key is pressed, but it has not been doing that.

```
from pygame.locals import*
import pygame

def main():   
    pygame.init()
    window = pygame.display.set_mode([200, 200])
    pygame.display.set_caption('game')

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():                           
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_PLUS]:
                    print "Pressed"

        clock.tick(60)

    pygame.quit()

main()
```

Does anyone know of a working alternative?

Comment: When you say the plus key, do you need the user to just press the key on the keyboard with the plus sign and the equals sign, or do they have to be also holding shift while they press that same key?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if the user is pressing the plus key with the shift key held down (which will result in typing a "+") then you can use:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.unicode == "+":
        print "Pressed"
```

This checks for if the user has types a "+" character so it works for both the "+" character on the keyboard and on the numpad. If you don't want the numpad "+" to be accepted then you can also check that `event.key == 61` (The key code for the "+" on the main keyboard).

If you don't care about whether they have shift held down or not, then you can just use:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_EQUALS:
        print "Pressed"
```

as the plus key is on the equals key.